Refreshing/Restarting the Apache Camel Route to use the latest property values from Property Service insted of Restarting the IG APP
We created an IG APP and using the route.property and Property Service to configure the property values based on the environment.
We are using the Boolean Flag to RouteBuild.configure() method to check of the App Events are enabled or not. this configure() method gets executed during the application startup so when we update the boolean flag via Property service, it won't reflect in the application at Runtime.
public void configure() throws Exception {
this.logger = IGLoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getContext());
String appEventsEnabled = getContext().resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{appevents.enabled}}");
logger.info("is AppEvents Enabled " + appEventsEnabled, "APP_EVENT");
}
I tried the Guidewire Provided option to Decative/Active Camel route option but it didn't help.
Is there any option to Stop/Start the RouteBuilder without Restarting the application or any other option to Dynamically reload the latest Property?

GW Article # 000044126 might help.
It states:
"Do not call the resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{property_name}}") method inside the toD() method. Please refer to GW docs where the code uses it inside the process() method"
Guidewire documentation:
If you intend to resolve properties using methods other than the Simple Expression Language, a server restart is not required to adopt the refreshed property value. For instance:
from("direct:/helios/resolveProperty")
    .id(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".2")
    .process((exchange) -> {
    exchange.getIn().setBody(this.getCamelContext().resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{greeting.common}}"));
    })
    .to("log:MyLog");


Thanks for your inputs but i was looking for a solution with in configure() method of Route. based on my research, these route classes are Singleton class and configure() method gets executed only at the server startup. IG App app need to restarted if application is referring any property values.
